# Mathematica asycn rendering of ListPlot

Tags: mathematica

I'm currently working on some graph theory, and I'm checking the robustness of graphs, by removing random vertices from a graph and then check how many vertices are outside the giant component. Then I'll do that for a lot of vertices, and plot them using ListPlot.

This takes along time to calculate, is there a way I can visualise it, that it plots something everytime a value is calculated.

```
thisFunctionTakesVeryLongAndReturnsAList := ....
ListPlot[thisFunctionTakesVeryLongAndReturnsAList [graph]]
```

thisFunctionTakesVeryLongAndReturnsAList  calculates a value that can be plotted all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timo,

If you have *Mathematica* 6 or later, you can use `Dynamic` for this. You should rewrite your `thisFunctionTakesVeryLongAndReturnsAList` like this:

```
list = {};
calculateOnePointVeryLong[x_] := (Pause[1]; result = {x, x^2}; 
   AppendTo[list, result]; result);
Graphics[Point[Dynamic[list]], Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
makeList = Table[calculateOnePointVeryLong[x], {x, 0, 10}];
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks I'll check into this :)